# How to specify the type of TItem in Virtualize Component in Blazor WebAssembly inside a Generic Table Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm building a Generic Table Template in my `blazor webassembly` project. Following the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0), I setup my table template and I'm trying to enable virtualization in my table template as follows.

**TableTemplate.razor:**

```
@typeparam TItem

<table class="@CssClass">
    <thead>
        <tr>@TableHeader</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Virtualize)
        {
            <Virtualize Context="item" Items="Items">
                <ItemContent>
                    <tr>@RowTemplate(item)</tr>
                </ItemContent>
                <Placeholder>
                    <p>Loading..</p>
                </Placeholder>
            </Virtualize>
        }
        else
        {
            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <tr>@RowTemplate(item)</tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**TableTemplate.razor.cs:**

```
public partial class TableTemplate<TItem>
{
    [Parameter]
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Virtualize { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment TableHeader { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TItem> RowTemplate { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IReadOnlyList<TItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm getting the below error,

> The type arguments for method
> 'TypeInference.CreateVirtualize_0(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int,
> ICollection, int, RenderFragment, int,
> RenderFragment)' cannot be inferred from the
> usage.

How to specify the type if `TItem` in Virtualize component? Please assist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TItem` is a generic type, so you need to hand it over to the `virtualize` component (which is also a generic type) like so:

```
@typeparam TItem

<table class="@CssClass">
    <thead>
        <tr>@TableHeader</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Virtualize)
        {
            <Virtualize Context="item" Items="Items" TItem="TItem">
                <ItemContent>
                    <tr>@RowTemplate(item)</tr>
                </ItemContent>
                <Placeholder>
                    <p>Loading..</p>
                </Placeholder>
            </Virtualize>
        }
        else
        {
            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <tr>@RowTemplate(item)</tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also your items cannot be `public IReadOnlyList<TItem> Items { get; set; }` as you'll get an exception that it can't convert it to an `ICollection<TItem>`

So that part should be:

```
    [Parameter]
    public ICollection<TItem> Items { get; set; }
```

Comment: This was mentioned in the above by Ron at the end but I wanted to add, I had to change my collection from IEnumerable to ICollection.  Once I made that ONLY change my Blazor page started working. I did NOT have to set TItem.  Thanks Ron Sijm for the info above.